# Windows 10 Resource monitor, Network sent/received bandwidth not match the graph

Tags: networking, windows-10, bandwidth, resource-monitor

Resource monitoring screenshot:

[image]

In Windows 10 Resource monitoring, network section, I always find that the detailed network traffic (no 1 in the Figure) doesn't match the graphical view (no 3 in the Figure).

As you can see the total traffic (no 1) of all process is much less than what is shown in the graphical view (no 2).

Is there any reason for that? Which process is consuming the rest of the bandwidth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The total traffic of all process is much less than what is shown in the graphical view.

The units are different.

1. 117346 B/s (bytes per second)
2. 915 Kbps (kilobits per second)

Converting 915 Kbps to B/s gives 114375, which is close enough for most purposes:

[image]